# Monitor Directory for PDF files and if pdf files are added then merge the PDF and delete the originals

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, filesystems, pdf-generation, monitoring

I would like to create a directory and have Ubuntu monitor for PDF files.

When a single PDF file is added, trigger a script. This script should first wait 30 sec for the copy procedure to finish. Then merge the PDF using `pdfunite` to a file called MERGED.pdf and delete the source files.

If a MERGED.pdf file exists then do nothing. The user should remove the MERGED.pdf file for a new conversion to start.

I am having trouble defining the process and the checks. If I copy 5 files, how do I trigger the script only once?

This is what I have done until now.

This script runs using a cronjob at reboot

```
#!/bin/bash

# The directory to monitor where the pdf files are added
dir="/path/to/directory"

# Use inotifywait to monitor the directory for changes
while true; do
  inotifywait -e create $dir | while read path action file; do
    # When a file is created in the directory
    if [ "$action" == "CREATE" ]; then
      # Run the script
      /path/to/merge_script.sh
    fi
  done
done
```

and this is the code to merge the pdfs

```
#!/bin/bash

# The directory to monitor
dir="/path/to/directory"

# Wait for files to be added to the directory
while true; do
  # Count the number of PDF files in the directory
  pdf_count=$(ls $dir/*.pdf | wc -l)

  # If there are more than 1 PDF files
  if [ $pdf_count -gt 1 ]; then
    # Wait for 30 seconds
    sleep 30

    # Count the number of PDF files again
    pdf_count=$(ls $dir/*.pdf | wc -l)

    # If there are still more than 1 PDF files
    if [ $pdf_count -gt 1 ]; then
      # Check if MERGED.pdf already exists
      if [ ! -f $dir/MERGED.pdf ]; then
        # Merge the PDF files
        pdfunite $dir/*.pdf $dir/MERGED.pdf

        # Delete the original PDF files
        rm $dir/*.pdf
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

However it is not working.

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: How do you ensure the new PDF files are complete before you try processing them?

Comment: And how do you ensure `rm $dir/*.pdf` doesn't remove *new* PDF files that were created while you were processing others?